# How to pass state and events handlers as props to children components with Vue.js's Router?

Tags: vue.js, routes, parameter-passing, vue-component, vue-router

Before using routing, I had the following `Dashboard` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <RegistrationForm v-on:add-employee="addEmployee" />
    <EmployeeTable
      v-bind:employees="employees"
      v-on:delete-employee="deleteEmployee"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
...
export default {
  components: {
    EmployeeTable,
    RegistrationForm
  },
  data() {
    return {
      employees: []
    };
  },
  methods:{
    deleteEmployee() {...}
    addEmployee() {...}
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to have to separate routes one for registering a new employee and one for listing all employees, so what I did first is updating the above template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then I defined a router object:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/dashboard",
            name: "dashboard",
            component: Dashboard,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'add-employee',
                    component: RegistrationForm, 
                },
                {
                    path: 'list-employees',
                    component: EmployeeTable, 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

My question is how to pass the `employees` state variable and `deleteEmployee`, `addEmployee` methods from the `Dashboard` component to its children components?

**Update:**
I do not know why I did not receive any response on this question, although this is a common and trivial task to do in other frameworks, for instance in `React`:

```
...
export default function BasicExample() {
  const [x, setX] = useState("World");
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home x={x}/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home({x}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {x}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After using *Vue-router* for a short period of time, I concluded that this is not a limitation, but more like a design decision:

- *React-router*: is more like a condional renderer, e.i from within the parent component and based on the current path, render the apporopriate child.
- *Vue-router*: is more like a wiring solution.

Also I have to say: a similar behavior to *React-router* can be achieved using *Vue-router*. This by combining the router's `currentRoute` [property](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute) with the `v-if` directive, which truly insert/remove a component from the DOM (not hiding it using *css* as `v-show` do).

Finally: seprating routes configuration is advantegeous, as it yield more modular project and better SPA. Of-course this separation can be done in both *Vue-router* and *React-router* (look [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config) for *React-router*).